# Function of the extra .pom file with a jar in Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory, maven-publish

I am using a gradle maven-publish plugin to deploy the artifact in the Artifactory. I can see that a folder with the package is being created but in that folder only the jar file exits and no .pom file exits.

Normally in the artifactory publish examples I have seen that each folder (version) contains the jar file and a .pom file.

My Questions are -
1. Is it necessary to have the supporting .pom file inside the folder?
2. What exactly the .pom functions in there?

Thanks

Comment: Without the extra pom file, it is unlikely that dependencies are resolved correctly.

Comment: @JFMeier But if I am trying to use the published artifact as dependency I am able to use that - successfully resolved the dependency.

Comment: I mean that the dependencies of your dependency might not be resolved.

Comment: So, If I add "the dependencies of dependency" in the project as dependencies also then It should not be an issue, right?

Comment: Maybe not. But it would be better to have a proper artifact in Artifactory that also has a POM.

Comment: @JFMeier thanks for the info. Agreed on proper artifact. But why do you think that adding "the dependencies of dependency" may not work?

Comment: I do not know much about Gradle, but Maven would definitely complain about a missing POM and I would not be sure that the resulting resolution is right. In any case, it is a very poor solution to try to add the dependencies yourself.

Comment: I know it's a very poor solution. Actually at this moment we don't have control over the artifactory I am referring to. Anyway, thanks for your comment. Cheers